# Extract middle part of string Teradata

Tags: regex, teradata

I am stuck trying to figure out why my REGEX expression in Teradata works sometimes but not always: i am trying to extract part of the string in the middle that has a pattern: it starts with ABC and is followed by 3 or 4 digits.

```
select RegExp_Substr('X886782E-ABC2036-VACCINE COVID', '[ABC]+[0-9]+')
```

My logic works most of the time, but not always: it does not always recogize part of the string that starts with ABC and is followed by 3-4 digits.

Comment: `[ABC]+` matches one or more capital letters, *each of which* is `'A'`, `'B'` or `'C'`, such as `'CAA'`. You want `ABC[0-9]+` (or `ABC\d+`), or possibly `\bABC[0-9]+` to prevent a match of `ZABC123'` or possibly `(?<=-)ABC[0-9]+` if the string must always follow a hyphen. The last is a *positive lookbehind*. I don't know if Teradata's regex engine supports lookbehinds.

Comment: thank you, Cary. I have tried all of these options and they all work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Cary Stoveland's help, either of these line of code will help extract middle part of the string that starts with ABC and is followed by 3-4 digits:

```
select RegExp_Substr('X886782E-ABC2036-VACCINE COVID', 'ABC[0-9]+')
select RegExp_Substr('X886782E-ABC2036-VACCINE COVID', 'ABC\d+')
select RegExp_Substr('X886782E-ABC2036-VACCINE COVID', '\bABC[0-9]+')
select RegExp_Substr('X886782E-ABC2036-VACCINE COVID', '(?<=-)ABC[0-9]+')
```

Comment: If you want exactly 3 or 4 digits: `\bABC[0-9]{3,4}`